Forever Undecided Chapter 4 - is the answer correct?
Just started reading this book and I’m confused by the answer suggested for this puzzle (No 2 in Chapter 4):
(On an island where all the inhabitants are either Knights, who always tell the truth, and Knaves, who always lie)

Two natives A and B say:
A: if either of us is a knight then Oona is on the Island.
B: That is true
Is Oona on the Island?

(You don’t know if A and B are knights or knaves.)
The solution given in the book says:

If either one is a knight, then the statement he made is true, from which it in turn follows that Oona is on the island. Therefore, if either one is a knight, Oona is on the island. Thus the statement they both made is true, hence both are knights, so surely at least one of them is a knight. From this and the truth of the statement they made, it follows that Oona is in the Island.

But the solution doesn’t consider if both A and B are knaves and therefore are both liars.
In that case statement A is false and statement B, affirming the truth of A, is false.
From that I’d conclude that there’s no way of telling if Oona is on the island as both statements are either true or both statements are false.
Am I missing something?

If $A$ were a Knave then $A's$ claim must be a lie,  which means that one If them must be Knight and yet $O$ is off the island.  But then...

If both are knaves then statement $A$ is true because the antecedent is false.

Hmm... looked up the google book.  He says is going to keep the answers shorter than before.  He does seem to have completely forgotten to consider if neither are knights. (In which case THE STATEMENT is contradictory true) and he also seems to have forgotten to point out the obvious that both islanders are claiming THE STATEMENT.  Perhaps he had shown in an earlier puzzle that if anyone ever makes a statement "If at least of us are knights then SOMETHING" always means at least one of them is a knight.

What I was missing was the condition that a knight must make a true statement and a knave must make a false statement.
The original statement was:

Two natives A and B say:
A: if either of us is a knight then Oona is on the Island.
B: That is true
Is Oona on the Island?

If either A or B is a knight then Ooona is present. If Speaker A was a Knave, and lying, Speaker B must be a Knight and would say False. So, if at least one of the speakers is a Knight then both have to be Knights.
But what if neither is a knight? Then statement A is spoken by a Knave and that's not possible because statement A does not say anything about Oona's presence if the speaker is a Knave.
To demonstrate this, I coded the following in C++:
using SPEAKER = bool;
constexpr SPEAKER KNIGHT = true;
constexpr SPEAKER KNAVE = false;

bool isOonaOnIsland(SPEAKER a, SPEAKER b) {
    if (a == KNIGHT || b == KNIGHT) {
        return true;
    }
}

When I compile this, my trusty compiler states:

warning: control reaches end of non-void function

In other words, if neither speaker is a Knight, the code needs an else statement to capture what a Knave would say. But, as we have no else statement then we are in what the C++ Standard terms 'undefined behaviour' - Oona's presence is neither confirmed nor denied if both speakers are Knaves. Neither are lying. Neither are saying anything.
So, if Speaker A is a Knave, he is 'taking the fifth' and making no comment about Oona's whereabouts. But as a Knave must tell a lie then he cannot take the fifth.
So, as it stands, under the admittedly arbitrary rules of the logic game, only a Knight could say statement A, so statement A must be true, so Oona is on the Island.
If the speaker of statement B had said 'False' then he would be Knave and telling a lie.
The book mentions in Chapter 3, page 18:

Theorem 1: Given any proposition p, suppose a native of the Knight-Knave island says: "If I am a knight, then P". Then the native must be a Knight and p must be true.

It goes on to say:

It also follows from Theorem 1 that no inhabitant of the Knight-Knave island can say "If I am a Knight, then Santa Claus exists" (unless Santa does exist)

A Knight cannot say that because it's a lie and a Knave cannot say it because he needs to tell a lie - he'd need to add the else statement:

If I am a Knight, then Santa Claus exists otherwise Santa Claus exists

I am definitely making an assumption here that the statement

If I am a knight, then "true statement" else "false statement"

is NOT equivalent to someone saying:

A knight would say: "statement"

because a Knave would, in the second instance, then lie about what a Knight would say.
The book goes on to discuss the stronger condition: x is true if and only if..., which clearly implies an else statement. I think I was subconsciously bringing in the else statement into statement A above, instead of just taking it as an absolute.
I think this makes sense...
Later chapters of the book provide truth tables and such from which he says some of the puzzles he set can be solved. But he doesn’t say which ones can and which ones can’t! I may update this answer if they shed better light on the solution than I have.
I think I'll now do something easier and invent a time machine :-)
